# How can I get SimpleForm to include a script tag once when a custom input is used?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm using the [Chosen widget](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) with a custom input inheriting from CollectionInput in SimpleForm 2.

To activate Chosen, the javascript `<script>$(".chzn-select").chosen();</script>` must appear somewhere on the page. It would be nice if I could get `simple_form_for` to automatically append it to the page if one or more custom inputs that require Chosen are used in the form. Is there a way to do this, short of forking the gem or doing some potentially fragile monkey patching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it unobtrusive way. Set class "chosen" to every input you want to apply widget. And then, somewhere in assets/javascripts

```
$(".chosen").each(function(){$(this).chosen()})
```

Comment: But the vast majority of the pages on in the project won't have the widget on them. It seems a bit wasteful to execute the javascript on every single page load.

Comment: If there are no elements with class `chosen` - iterations will not be performed - where is waste?

Comment: It's still running the select on every page.

Comment: Server wastes are more important than client wastes